# Executing a unix command in cygwin launched from ant in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, cygwin

I have an ant build for a java project that I would like to trigger from within eclipse, that in turn launches a cygwin window that executes a deployment script. Is it possible to implement this without calling a new command window from ant?

Answer (score 0):

Use bash.exe as the executable (replacing or parameterizing cygwin directory as needed):

```
<project default="default">
  <target name="default">
    <exec executable="c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe">
      <arg value="-c"/>
      <arg value="ls c:/"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error...
[exec] /usr/bin/bash: ls: command not found

Comment: @bakoyaro That sounds like a Cygwin misconfiguration issue of some kind.  Perhaps changing `ls c:/` to `echo $PATH` would give a clue.  Or change to `/bin/ls` if you just want to see it working.

Comment: I agree, the path seems to not be working as expected. I'll keep trying and post back here if I find anything